# view table not displaying

Tags: php, laravel, forms, eloquent, display

i've tried almost every code but still not working for me i'm trying to search multiple queries at the same time from different fields i finally managed to get all the values of variables on view page in an array but can't display it on page LIKE:

```php
@foreach($businesses AS $business)
   {{$business->id}} {{$business->name}} {{$business->email}}
```

but it is not getting the value from controller the code is

```php
$businesses['businesses'] = DB::table("businesses")->where("city", "=", $_GET['id'])->where("email", "=", $_GET['email'])->where("name", "=", $_GET['name'])->get(); 
return view('searchbusinessnew',$businesses)->with('bc');
```

[results in my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VDOn.png)

Comment: what does your `with['bc'] mean?

Comment: did you defined `$businesses = array();` before the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
$businesses = array();
$businesses['businesses'] = DB::table("businesses")->where("city", "=", $request->get('id'))->where("email", "=", $request->get('email'))->where("name", "=", $request->get('name'))->get(); 
return view('searchbusinessnew', [
            'businesses' => $businesses
        ]);
```